# Advantages of Sharepoint vs other ECM software?

Tags: ecm

I am looking for an ECM solution for a 40 person real estate development company. I need to to choose which version of Sharepoint is appropriate for the organization but also need to identify its advantages over other software. What are the advantages of Sharepoint besides integration with office? Also, how much administrative support is required to install, maintain, and develop workflows in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

The standard answer for a 40 person company is to look into Office 365. With that, there's no server costs, no one has to install or patch the servers, etc., just sign up for the service and start using it within a few minutes.

Administrative support for workflow? Well, someone has to create the workflows, but I certainly can't say what effort that will take without knowing the complexity of the workflows you have in mind.

Comment: To piggy back off of the O365 suggestion, Nintex offers an app that is reasonably priced per user if you are looking for complex workflows outside of what SharePoint Designer might offer you.

Comment: So with Office 365 you receive the Sharepoint Foundation which has the document storage functionality? What functionality do you not have with Office 365 version of Sharepoint? Also, how would I find the appropriate support or implementation professional for this job that I can speak with?

Comment: To be specific, "SharePoint Foundation" is a reference to the free version of SharePoint, but Office 365 provides quite a bit more than that. Here's a link to the plan comparison page: https://products.office.com/en-us/business/compare-more-office-365-for-business-plans. What do you get with on-prem? On prem allows integration with SQL Reporting Services which is currently lacking in the cloud version. Though, the cloud version is being updated more often, and so has more functionality at the moment. (some folks like the idea of on-prem being updates less frequently, so that's a plus to some)

Comment: Again, sorry if it seems like my answer is sales. I just know that a lot of smaller companies like the idea of not having to maintain their own servers, and I know the complexity of installing and configuring SharePoint, and dealing with things like backups, etc. If you check it out and don't mind paying someone to help with the process, perhaps find a local user group and ask for references. Or, MS provides a search tool to find "partners" that specialize in this sort of thing: https://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/search?type=companies&keyword=springhouse